# Localizable.strings from framework is not getting inside framework

Tags: ios, swift, localization, cocoapods, bundle

I have a project with some basic functionalities which I can reuse and I am trying to use that as a framework in another project. So my podspec includes strings, swift, assets files and all got added in to the project but the strings keys are not taking the value from localizables.strings. Basically it is not getting from the bundle path. Here is the code where I am calling the strings file inside the framework. "path" is getting as nil. It is working fine in the base project

```
let bundle: Bundle = .main
if let currentLanguage = languageManager.getCurrentLanguage() {
   if let path = bundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.rawValue, ofType: "lproj"),
      let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {
          return bundle.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: nil)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.. In podspec, it was

```
spec.resource_bundle = { 'AppName' => ['AppName/**/*.{strings}'] }
```

I changed it to

```
spec.resources = "AppName/**/*.{xcassets}", "AppName/**/*.{Strings}"
```